# Standard RedHat set of rpms for Anaconda?

Tags: python, redhat, anaconda

I would like to install the standard Anaconda distribution (http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/index) for Python on our servers, but I am not allowed to use 'third party' software. Does anyone know of a standard RedHat or EPEL set of rpms for this so we can do a yum install on the pkgs? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: anaconda is commercial third party software. Wrapping it in gift paper will not change that.